# XCUITest: Auto-Accepting System-Alerts. Need more fine grained control

Tags: ios, xcode-ui-testing

I have read that `addUIInterruptionMonitorWithDescription` could be used to accept / tap on a particular button in a system alert. On recently trying some test code out, I was doing the following:

- Adding a Photos Alert
- Adding a Calendar Alert
- Adding a Location Alert.

On the simulator, I was surprised to find that the Calendar and Location prompt automatically had their "Allow" buttons tapped. For the Photos prompt, the "Don't Allow" was hit. My question is - is there no need for `addUIInterruptionMonitorWithDescription` anymore? I tried using it for tapping on the dialogs but it didn't do anything. Even when I tried to hit another button on the alerts, I didn't see it working. How do I tap on the individual buttons on a system alert her?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is an alert on screen, and none of your interruption handlers handle it, XCTest will dismiss it for you if you are using Xcode <9.1.

To gain control of the alerts, you should create an interruption handler for each alert, returning `true` from the closure when (**and only when**) you have handled the alert that handler was intended for.

If the test tries all your alert handlers or receives a `true` return value from any of your handlers, and there is still an alert on screen, XCTest will handle the alert itself.

Comment: Thanks! This is great.

Comment: "If there is an alert on screen, and none of your interruption handlers handle it, XCTest will dismiss it for you." <- Doesn't work with XCUITest in Xcode9.1.

Comment: Hm, yes I've noticed that. That's the trouble with relying on undocumented behaviour... it might change at any time. I'll update my answer.